Selenium(chrome driver) and Gunicorn problem workers close immediately after starting with daemon
I'm publishing my app to a vps everything works great when starting the app using runserver or normal testing with Gunicorn but when trying to run my server through Gunicorn the driver keeps crushing
any help please ?
ideas to help fix the problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
